# Can I associate a user's account with an action to the drive API?

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-oauth

We're looking to make a little webapp to manage our week-long nerf war (humans vs zombies to be precise), and we're thinking about how easy it would be to have Google Sheets be our only backend, and our frontend be entirely javascript/html/css.

Let's say there's two actions that can be done in this javascript:

1. Register, which adds a row to a certain sheet.
2. Report tag, which adds a row to another sheet.

Let's say we have 100 players. We'll have each player sign in using a google account. Is there a way that for either of those above actions, we can have sheets know who made that action?

This way, if someone gets hold of the API key and spoofs their referer to make bad requests, then we can know which google account did it and ban them from the game.

For example, if I open up my sheet and say "see revision history", I want to not see one user for all the revisions, I want to see the user who triggered the action.

Is this a reasonable approach, and is it possible? Thanks!

(note: i know these two actions can be done via google forms, which can associate the user's account, but imagine we have more complex actions that cant be achieved with just a google form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. You'll be using the spreadsheets API (NOT the Drive API) to update the sheet.As far as Google is concerned, the "user" is your application, regardless of which human was driving the application at the time. Your application knows who the human is, and so it is responsible for logging any audit info that your use case may require.

Comment: thanks! that helps a bunch. a quick followup question if you don't mind: what's stopping a sophisticated user from just looking at the outgoing requests, grabbing my api key and doc url from the source code and wreaking havoc on my sheets?

Comment: Any attempt to access the sheet must contain a valid, current access token.The access token can only be generated when both of the following are true, 1/ the request came from your app (verified by client ID and origin), and 2/ there was a human logged in to a Google session.

Comment: It seems like it would be easy to get around this though. Can't the user: 1. Log into my page with their google account, 2. Do an action that causes a request to be sent, 3. Look in the network tab to see the client ID, 4. Use curl with that same client ID, setting a header to make the origin seem like my app, to send any sheets API request they want? Perhaps download the entire sheet, perhaps delete everything, perhaps increase his or her own score in the game... possible?

Comment: I haven't examined all of the attack vectors, but in principle, I agree that nothing from the client can be trusted and so fraudulent http packets are always a possibility. Where there is a risk of damage in such a scenario you probably need to move to a server app, or at least a server proxy which blocks any vulnerabilities, eg by vetting the user ID or preventing certain operations. OAuth uses scopes to limit what an app can do, but that relies on the service provider (Google in this case) to implement a range of fine grained scopes that you can choose from.